# Me suscribo 2 veces al entrar nuevamente en la pagina

Tags: angular7, ionic4

Tengo un pequeño problema, tengo un proyecto en ionic 5, donde en la pagina 2 me suscribo a un servicio que me entrega la hora del equipo (smartphone), si cargo la pagina me muestra en consola la hora normalmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al volver a la pagina 1 ocupo unsuscribe() para de suscribirme del servicio y efectivamente deja de mostrarme la hora del equipo

y al retornar nuevamente a la pagina 2 me suscribo a mi servicio pero me muestra en consola 2 veces la hora y no puedo hacer mi logica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código

```
relojeria() {
var hora = null;
this.datos$ = this.reloj.getInfoReloj();
this.subcripcion = this.datos$.subscribe(x => {
  hora = x.hora + ':' + x.minutos + ':' + x.segundo;
  console.log(hora);
});
```

}

y este es mi servicio

```
getInfoReloj(): Observable<valorReloj> {
this.clock.subscribe(t => {
  this.hours = t.getHours() % 24;
  //this.hours = this.hours ? this.hours : 24;
  this.vr = {
    hora: (t.getHours() < 10) ? '0' + t.getHours() : t.getHours().toString(),
    minutos: (t.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + t.getMinutes() : t.getMinutes().toString(),
    ampm: t.getHours() > 11 ? 'PM' : 'AM',
    diaymes: t.toLocaleString('es-MX', { day: '2-digit', month: 'long' }).replace('.', '').replace('-', ' '),
    diadesemana: t.toLocaleString('es-MX', { weekday: 'long' }).replace('.', ''),
    segundo: t.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + t.getSeconds() : t.getSeconds().toString()
  }
  this.infofecha$.next(this.vr);
});
return this.infofecha$.asObservable().p;
```

}

Alguien ha tenido este problema y lo ha solucionado

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola He encontrado mi respuesta, después de mucho intentar y leer literatura estaba haciendo mi servicio de reloj un singleton ( declarando en el @NgModule mi servicio). Por esta razón mi servicio estara vivo mientras viva mi aplicación aunque en el ngOndestroy me desuscriba del servicio

la solución fue que en el componente  declarar en los provider el servicio del reloj

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menuguard',
  templateUrl: './menuguard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menuguard.page.scss'],
  providers: [RelojService]
})
```

Con declarar providers: [RelojService] al destruir el componente destruye nuestro servicio y así liberamos memoria, entonces al cargar nuevamente el componente Page2 llamara a nuestro servicio nuevamente

Espero que les sirva a alguien

Saludos